# RestTemplate and deserializing nested List

Tags: json, spring, resttemplate

This is my class, and json I want to map to object using RestTemplate. I know it's not the best design but anyway. Mapping goes only as deep as returning LockerReservations with empty reservations Array. When there are reservations in the list it doesn't even map them.

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class LockerReservations {
    Locker locker;
    List<Reservation> reservations;
}
```

```
[
    {
        "locker": {
            "id": 0,
            "size": "S"
        },
        "reservations": []
    },
    {
        "locker": {
            "id": 1,
            "size": "S"
        },
        "reservations": []
    },
    {
        "locker": {
            "id": 4,
            "size": "S"
        },
        "reservations": [
            {
                "id": 17,
                "start": "2023-03-14T06:37:07.006",
                "end": "2023-03-14T12:37:07.006",
                "user": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "Kiemoon"
                },
                "locker": {
                    "id": 4,
                    "size": "S"
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 36,
                "start": "2023-03-14T14:37:07.006",
                "end": "2023-03-14T15:37:07.006",
                "user": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "Kiemoon"
                },
                "locker": {
                    "id": 4,
                    "size": "S"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

That's my method that utilizes RestTemplate:

```
    public List<LockerReservations> getReservationsCheck2(Size size, LocalDateTime start, LocalDateTime end) {

        HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        Map<String, Object> sizeTimeMap = new HashMap<>();
        sizeTimeMap.put("size", size.toString());
        sizeTimeMap.put("start", start.toString());
        sizeTimeMap.put("end", end.toString());
        HttpEntity<Map<String, Object>> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<>(sizeTimeMap, httpHeaders);
        LockerReservations[] exchange = restTemplate.postForObject(url + "reservationsCheck", httpEntity, LockerReservations[].class);
        return Arrays.asList(exchange);
    }
```

How to get full deserialization?

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this:

```
    public List<LockerReservations> getReservationsCheck(Size size, LocalDateTime start, LocalDateTime end) throws JsonProcessingException {

    HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    Map<String, Object> sizeTimeMap = new HashMap<>();
    sizeTimeMap.put("size", size.toString());
    sizeTimeMap.put("start", start.toString());
    sizeTimeMap.put("end", end.toString());
    HttpEntity<Map<String, Object>> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<>(sizeTimeMap, httpHeaders);
    String str = restTemplate.postForObject(url + "reservationsCheck", httpEntity, String.class);
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
    objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
    JavaType type = objectMapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(List.class, LockerReservations.class);
    List<LockerReservations> lockerReservationsList = objectMapper.readValue(str, type);
    return lockerReservationsList;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).